# what is a cute way to call a moth?

Tags: словоупотребление

how would you call a moth cutely? in german an example is lein and chen are word endings that make things cute.. or small. so hund is dog... hundchen is a cute dog.. or puppy. i know in russian the word is Mol for moth. but what word ending goes with this to make it cute?

Comment: мотылёчек, but never use моль, it is very derogatory.

Answer (score 2):

A moth has several meanings: **моль** is an insect which we don't like much for spoiling (making holes)in fur,wool,etc. So I don't think we have a diminutive word for it.
But the second meaning is **мотылёк**,a sort of a little butterfly and it sounds the way you need.In general we use suffixes for that purpose:

> птица--птичка,цветок--цветочек.

Answer (score 2):

if by `moth` you mean `a butterfly (бабочка)` and not `a moth (моль)` whos larvae subsist on clothes, then the phonetic pattern the word `бабочка` is formed by already has the feminine diminutive-affectionate suffіx `-чка`, so can't be any cuter than it already is :^)

another such suffix mostly for feminine nouns is `-(нь)ка`, `-уля`, mostly for masculine nouns `-ок/ёк`, `-ик`, a rather ancient fossil suffix `-ушк`

> мама - мАмочка, мамУля
>
> мать - мАтушка
>
> собака - собАчка, (colloquial) собАнька
>
> пёс - пЁсик

for adjectives and adverbs `-еньк/оньк-`

> малый - мAленький, мАхонький
>
> красный - крАсненький
>
> легко - легOнько
>
> мало - малЕнько

and for personal names, along with the aforementioned, these are: colloquial `-юня/юся`, more normative `-аша/юша`

> Андрей - АндрЮня, АндрЮша
>
> Коля - КолЮня, КОленька
>
> Боря - БорЮся, БОренька
>
> Наталья - НатАша
>
> Любовь, Люба - ЛюбАша, ЛюбОк, ЛЮбочка
>
> Таня - ТанЮша, ТАнечка
>
> Света - СветУля, СвЕтик, СвЕточка